# Comparison of Export Options for Pandas

Tags: pandas, export

As I've begun to work with larger data sets, exporting them to CSV files is starting to seem slow, and inefficient. Thus, I thought it would be prudent to start a thread comparing the different export options for DataFrames.

Comment: There is an [entire section of the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#performance-considerations) dedicated to some basic benchmarks for read/write performance for different file types.  TLDR, you should consider `pickle`, which is fast and has the added benefit that it can serialize python objects, unlike a basic `csv`

Comment: Thanks @ALollz. I was also hoping to get more of a discussion going here about things other than timing that may be useful. For instance, preserving data types across a export/import cycle, ease of use for importing the data into other programs such as Origin or MatLab, etc.

Comment: QAs on Stack Overflow aren't meant to be overly broad all-encompassing posts. They focus on a single specific issue and provide a solution. This post seemed to call out speed, in which case `pickle` is the solution. If you need to preserve datatypes, again `pickle` is the solution. If you need to export to `matlab`, write a text file. But again without much more specific information about your workflow there's little else to say.

Comment: `QAs on Stack Overflow aren't meant to be overly broad all-encompassing posts.` Thanks, I didn't realize this bit of meta. 

A bit off topic, but is there a place to have a broader discussions?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your objective. 
But if you compare **to_csv** to **to_excel**, you will note that it is much faster to save a file as csv (about ten times faster). 
If you need to have a tabular output, then using **to_csv** should be your best bet.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import time

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

start = time.time()
df.to_csv('test.csv')
done = time.time()
elapsed = done - start
print(elapsed)
```

*Result for to_csv: 0.003989458084106445*

```
start = time.time()
df.to_excel('test.xlsx')
done = time.time()
elapsed = done - start
print(elapsed)
```

*Result for to_excel: 0.049866676330566406*

I hope it helps!
BR

Answer (score 0):

On the convenience side, `pickle`ing your data preserves the data's structure and data types. I've found this especially useful when using MultiIndexes, because you don't have to specify how many header rows and columns there are.